# darkening the body does not work, what is the problem?

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

I am trying to darken the rest of the html file when opening a modal, to open the modal you must press show and by doing this through the 'modalState' function the darken class will be added to the body. In this case add a red color as a test. The problem is that while the class is added nothing happens. What is the problem? What is the correct way to do it?

[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="dark">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <script>
      tailwind.config = {
        theme: {
          fontFamily:{
            Martel: ['Martel Sans', 'sans-serif'],
            Anton: ['Anton', 'sans-serif'],
            BebasNeue: ['Bebas Neue', 'cursive'],
            Electrolize: ['Electrolize', 'sans-serif'],
            GreatVibes: ['Great Vibes', 'cursive'],
            Parisienne: ['Parisienne', 'cursive'],
            PressStart: ['Press Start 2P', 'cursive'],
            Sacramento: ['Sacramento', 'cursive'], 
          },
          extend: {
            colors: {
              gray: {
                900: '#202225',
                800: '#2f3136',
                700: '#36393f',
                600: '#4f545c',
                400: '#d4d7dc',
                300: '#e3e5e8',
                200: '#ebedef',
                100: '#f2f3f5',
              },
              Greyple_Discord: '#99AAb5',
              Black_Discord: '#23272A',
              DarkButNotBlack_Discord: '#2C2F33',
              NotQuiteBlack_Discord: '#23272A',
              Blurple_Discord: '#5865F2',
              Green_Discord: '#57F287',
              Yellow_Discord: '#FEE75C',
              Fuchsia_Discord: '#EB459E',
              Red_Discord: '#ED4245',
            }
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css" > 

    <title>Cristian Orellana M.</title>
    <style>
      .darken {
        position:relative;
        box-shadow:0 0 0 1600px rgba(253, 24, 24, 0.65);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="dark:bg-DarkButNotBlack_Discord dark:text-white">
    <div>
      <div id="main_menu" class="invisible fixed top-0 left-0 m-0 flex h-screen w-32 flex-col bg-gray-900 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:text-white xl:visible 2xl:visible">
        <div class="relative mt-2 flex items-center justify-center text-center text-7xl">C</div>
        <div class="relative mt-4 flex items-center justify-center text-center">
          <p>Sobre Mi</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-40">
          <div class="sidebad">
            <i><p>Sobre Mi</p></i>
          </div>
          <div class="sidebad">
            <i><p>Habilidades</p></i>
          </div>
          <div class="sidebad">
            <i><p>Porfolio</p></i>
          </div>
          <div class="sidebad">
            <i><p>Contacto</p></i>
          </div>
          <div class="sidebad">
            <i><p>Blog</p></i>
          </div>
          <div class="sidebad">
            <i><p></p></i>
          </div>
          <div class="sidebad">
            <i
              ><p>
                <input type="radio" id="theme-dark" name="theme" checked /> <label>Dark</label><br />
                <input type="radio" id="theme-light" name="theme" />
                <label>Light</label>
              </p></i
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="main_body" class="p-1 xl:ml-32">
        <div class="mt-56 grid grid-cols-1 xl:grid-cols-2 2xl:grid-cols-2">
          <div class="border border-indigo-600">
            <div class="font-Martel p-1 text-5xl font-extrabold text-white sm:text-5xl md:p-10 md:text-5xl lg:text-7xl xl:text-7xl 2xl:text-7xl">

            </div>
            <div class="mt-10 p-10">
              <button class="btn-contact">testing</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="invisible border border-indigo-600 xl:visible 2xl:visible"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-10 py-20">
          <h1 class="font-Martel text-5xl font-extrabold text-indigo-600 sm:text-5xl md:text-5xl lg:text-7xl xl:text-7xl 2xl:text-7xl">Sobre Mi</h1>
          <br />
          <p class="dark:text-white">Mi nombre es Cristian Orellana Muñoz ¡Mucho gusto!. Soy un desarrollador de software en busca de nuevas oportunidades laborales, principalmente orientadas al desarrollo de aplicaciones web.</p>
          <p class="dark:text-white">Me gusta mucho aprender nuevas tecnologías para el desarrollo de software por lo que constantemente me encuentro haciendo cursos de este rubro.</p>
          <p class="dark:text-white">Si me quieres contratar debes de saber que soy una persona responsable y que valoro mucho el trabajo en equipo, considero importante el llevarse bien con quienes se trabaja y ayudar a quien lo necesite.</p>
          <br />
          <p class="dark:text-white"><b>Hobbies:</b> Esta es una lista de cosas que me gusta hacer</p>
          <br />
          <p class="dark:text-white">- Leer (Libros, Manga y Comics)</p>
          <p class="dark:text-white">- Ver series y películas</p>
          <p class="dark:text-white">- Hacer ejercicio (porque me mantiene saludable y en forma)</p>
          <p class="dark:text-white">- Y jugar a video juegos (Me encanta jugar con mis amigos ;D )</p>
        </div>

        <div class="py-20">
          <div class="bg-[url('images/work1.jpg')] p-10 sm:visible md:visible lg:bg-[length:1200px_280px] xl:bg-[length:1600px_280px] 2xl:bg-[length:1760px_280px]">
            <h2 class="font-Martel px-4 text-5xl font-extrabold text-indigo-600 sm:text-5xl md:text-5xl lg:text-7xl xl:text-7xl 2xl:text-7xl">Porfolio</h2>
            <br />
            <p class="px-4 text-white">Estos son algunos de los proyectos en los que he trabajado. En algunos projyectos trabaje en solitario y en otros trabaje con personas geniales.</p>
            <p class="px-4 text-white">Puedes pasar el mouse por una de las imagenes para ver más detalles.</p>
            <br />
          </div>

          <div class="grid w-full grid-cols-1 gap-1 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4">
            <div class="relative cursor-pointer overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg" id="project_1" onmouseover="ShowTextView(this.id);" onmouseout="HideTextView(this.id);">
              <img class="h-48 w-full object-cover opacity-50" id="img_proyect_1" src="https://comunidad.retorn.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2018/09/gatitos/3008811440.jpg" />
              <div class="absolute top-0 border-blue-300 py-20 text-center">
                <h4 class="bg-Blurple_Discord mb-3 px-20 text-center text-xl font-semibold tracking-tight text-white opacity-0" id="show_text_1" onclick="modalState();">Show</h4>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="relative cursor-pointer overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg" id="project_2" onmouseover="ShowTextView(this.id);" onmouseout="HideTextView(this.id);">
              <img class="h-48 w-full object-cover opacity-50" id="img_proyect_2" src="https://comunidad.retorn.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2018/09/gatitos/3008811440.jpg" />
              <div class="absolute top-0 border-blue-300 py-20 text-center">
                <h4 class="bg-Blurple_Discord mb-3 px-20 text-center text-xl font-semibold tracking-tight text-white opacity-0" id="show_text_2" onclick="modalState();">Show</h4>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="relative cursor-pointer overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg" id="project_3" onmouseover="ShowTextView(this.id);" onmouseout="HideTextView(this.id);">
              <img class="h-48 w-full object-cover opacity-50" id="img_proyect_3" src="https://comunidad.retorn.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2018/09/gatitos/3008811440.jpg" />
              <div class="absolute top-0 border-blue-300 py-20 text-center">
                <h4 class="bg-Blurple_Discord mb-3 px-20 text-center text-xl font-semibold tracking-tight text-white opacity-0" id="show_text_3">Show</h4>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="relative cursor-pointer overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg" id="project_4" onmouseover="ShowTextView(this.id);" onmouseout="HideTextView(this.id);">
              <img class="h-48 w-full object-cover opacity-50" id="img_proyect_4" src="https://comunidad.retorn.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2018/09/gatitos/3008811440.jpg" />
              <div class="absolute top-0 border-blue-300 py-20 text-center">
                <h4 class="bg-Blurple_Discord mb-3 px-20 text-center text-xl font-semibold tracking-tight text-white opacity-0" id="show_text_4">Show</h4>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="relative cursor-pointer overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg" id="project_5" onmouseover="ShowTextView(this.id);" onmouseout="HideTextView(this.id);">
              <img class="h-48 w-full object-cover opacity-50" id="img_proyect_5" src="https://comunidad.retorn.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2018/09/gatitos/3008811440.jpg" />
              <div class="absolute top-0 border-blue-300 py-20 text-center">
                <h4 class="bg-Blurple_Discord mb-3 px-20 text-center text-xl font-semibold tracking-tight text-white opacity-0" id="show_text_5">Show</h4>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="relative cursor-pointer overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg" id="project_6" onmouseover="ShowTextView(this.id);" onmouseout="HideTextView(this.id);">
              <img class="h-48 w-full object-cover opacity-50" id="img_proyect_6" src="https://comunidad.retorn.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2018/09/gatitos/3008811440.jpg" />
              <div class="absolute top-0 border-blue-300 py-20 text-center">
                <h4 class="bg-Blurple_Discord mb-3 px-20 text-center text-xl font-semibold tracking-tight text-white opacity-0" id="show_text_6">Show</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="card_panel" class="main-modal dark:NotQuiteBlack_Discord fixed inset-0 z-50 flex hidden w-full items-center justify-center overflow-hidden">
          <div class="modal-container z-50 mx-auto overflow-y-auto rounded-xl dark:bg-gray-900 dark:text-white sm:max-w-screen-sm md:max-w-screen-md lg:max-w-screen-lg xl:max-w-screen-xl 2xl:max-w-screen-2xl">
            <div class="modal-content py-4 px-6 text-left">
              <div class="flex items-center justify-between pb-3">
                <h2 class="font-Martel text-Blurple_Discord p-5 py-2 text-5xl font-bold sm:text-5xl md:text-5xl lg:text-7xl xl:text-7xl 2xl:text-7xl">Bruno Fritsch</h2>
                <div id="card_close" class="modal-close z-50 cursor-pointer" onclick="modalState();">
                  <svg class="fill-current text-gray-500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
                    <path d="M14.53 4.53l-1.06-1.06L9 7.94 4.53 3.47 3.47 4.53 7.94 9l-4.47 4.47 1.06 1.06L9 10.06l4.47 4.47 1.06-1.06L10.06 9z"></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="my-5 mr-5 ml-5 justify-center">
                <div>
                  <p>Empresa del rubro automotriz. Su sistema permite crear documentos de compra y venta, inventario, contratos, contabilidad y callcenter (Esta es la web de acceso público la del sistema de los empelados no puedo agregarla ).</p>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>
                  <img src="https://comunidad.retorn.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2018/09/gatitos/3008811440.jpg" />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>
                  <p>Puedes visitar el sitio en <a href="https://comunidad.retorn.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2018/09/gatitos/3008811440.jpg" target="_blank" class="text-blue-600">https://www.brunofritsch.cl/</a></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="my-5 mr-5 ml-5">
                <div>
                  <label class="dark:bg-DarkButNotBlack_Discord"><b>#PHP</b></label>
                  <label class="dark:bg-DarkButNotBlack_Discord"><b>#JAVASCRIPT</b></label>
                  <label class="dark:bg-DarkButNotBlack_Discord"><b>#BOOTSTRAP</b></label>
                  <label class="dark:bg-DarkButNotBlack_Discord"><b>#POSTGRESQL</b></label>
                  <label class="dark:bg-DarkButNotBlack_Discord"><b>#WEBSERVICES</b></label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="test_div"></div>
    <script src="src/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
let theme_dark = document.getElementById('theme-dark');
let theme_light = document.getElementById('theme-light');


theme_dark.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("pasa por theme dark")
    document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
});

theme_light.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("pasa por theme light")
    document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark')
});


const card_close = document.getElementById('card_close')
const card_panel = document.getElementById('card_panel')
const body = document.querySelector('body')
const main_body = document.getElementById('main_body')
const main_menu = document.getElementById('main_menu')
const test_div = document.getElementById('test_div')



function modalState() {
    if(card_panel.classList.contains('hidden')) {
        // Show modal
        card_panel.classList.remove('hidden')
        card_panel.classList.add('block')
        console.log(body)
        body.classList.add('darken')
        // Start animation open
        card_panel.classList.add('card_open')
    } else {
        // Delete modal
        card_panel.classList.add('hidden')
        card_panel.classList.remove('block')
        body.classList.remove('darken')
        // Show button


        // Remove animation open
        card_panel.classList.remove('card_open')
    }
}

function ModalShow(){
    const modal = document.getElementById("staticBackdrop")

    if(modal.classList.contains('hidden')) {
        // Show modal
        modal.classList.remove('hidden')
        modal.classList.add('block')

    } else {
        // Delete modal
        modal.classList.add('hidden')
        modal.classList.remove('block')
    }

}

/*
card_open.addEventListener('click', modalState)
card_close.addEventListener('click', modalState)
*/
function ShowTextView(id){
    console.log("pasa por function")
    console.log(id)
    const new_id = id.split("_")
    document.getElementById("show_text_"+new_id[1]).classList.remove("opacity-0"); 
    document.getElementById("img_proyect_"+new_id[1]).classList.remove("opacity-50"); 
}

function HideTextView(id){
    console.log("pasa por function")
    console.log(id)
    const new_id = id.split("_")
    document.getElementById("show_text_"+new_id[1]).classList.add("opacity-0"); 
    document.getElementById("img_proyect_"+new_id[1]).classList.add("opacity-50"); 
}
```

Comment: the post was modified, I hope your help

Comment: Will you please elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve with this code? What feature you are implementing?

Comment: when opening the modal, the rest of the elements are darkened. Something similar to what bootstrap does when opening a modal (Launch modal demo in this article) https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing this link I understood how to achieve the desired effect. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Adapting it to my code it looks like this:

```
<style>
  
  .darken {
    /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); /* Black w/ opacity */
  }
  
</style>
```

On the JS side, the style must be applied to the modal, not to the body (the id of the modal is card_panel)

```
function modalState() {
  if(card_panel.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    // Show modal
    card_panel.classList.remove('hidden')
    card_panel.classList.add('block')
    console.log(body)
    card_panel.classList.add('darken')
    // Start animation open
    card_panel.classList.add('card_open')
  } else {
    // Delete modal
    card_panel.classList.add('hidden')
    card_panel.classList.remove('block')
    card_panel.classList.remove('darken')

    // Show button
    // Remove animation open
    card_panel.classList.remove('card_open')
  }
 }
```